# Permission issue executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm running a job in a schedule under the service account [MyDomain][MyServiceAccount].

```
11/16/2011 13:40:40.32 BEGIN TASK "MyProc" 
Error 1088, Level 16, State 7, Procedure MyProc, Line 18, Message: Cannot find the object "MyTable" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
11/16/2011 13:40:40.69 - *** EOJ "MyProc.cmd" ***
```

Shouldn't this have solved the issue?

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[MyTable] TO [MyDomain]\[MyServiceAccount]. AS [dbo]
GO
GRANT INSERT ON [dbo].[MyTable] TO [MyDomain]\[MyServiceAccount]. AS [dbo]
GO
GRANT UPDATE ON [dbo].[MyTable] TO [MyDomain]\[MyServiceAccount]. AS [dbo]
GO
```

It did not. The procedure MYproc does an insert into table MyTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that in the proc i was doing a TRUNCATE of MYTABLE prior to inserting. Truncate requires elevated rights.